# How to convert the hexadecimal data into plain text or human readable text?

Tags: openssl, hex, plaintext

I want to convert the given hexadecimal text to plain text or human readable text.For that case i used many of online converters but i am unable to convert it.Though i got some output but that is not in human readable format.

Here example.
input: 8d02ca2f362e103bb410946c29d1

converted o/p : ��6.;��l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The � question mark characters in the converted text look like your input text is ASCII, not unicode. If your input text is converted to unicode, that may get rid of the � characters that appear in the converted text.

There are many programming calculators in all platforms that can convert hexadecimal to other numerical bases. You are using Ubuntu, so I will demonstrate how to convert hexadecimal to other numerical bases on Ubuntu's built-in Calculator application and also in the terminal using the built-in `bc` program.

#### Calculator app

1. Open the Calculator application and from the Calculator toolbar select *Mode* -> *Programming Mode*.
2. Copy your input hexadecimal number into the console, select *Hexadecimal* from the dropdown menu under the console, and press the  <kbd>**=**</kbd>  key on the calculator.

   [image: IMG:]
3. The input number will be shown in the console in bold text to indicate that it is ready to be converted. Select a new base from the base dropdown menu and the result will be shown in the console in bold text.

   [image: IMG:]

---

#### Terminal

To convert hexadecimal to decimal, set ibase (input base) to 16 in the following command:

```
echo "ibase=16; hex-number"|bc # replace hex-number with any hexadecimal number
```

To convert decimal to hexadecimal, set obase (output base) to 16 in the following command:

```
echo "obase=16; decimal-number"|bc # replace decimal-number with any decimal number
```